# C# check if XML file is not corrupted before deserialization

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, serialization, xml-serialization, filestream

I didn't find anything for my problem in internet.
I deserialize data for playlists.

He is my code :

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("playlist.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
 XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Playlist>));
 if (fs.Length > 0)
  pl = (ObservableCollection<Playlist>)xml.Deserialize(fs);
 else
  pl = new ObservableCollection<Playlist>();
}
```

Here is the result XML :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <ArrayOfPlaylist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <Playlist>
        <Name>Playlist1</Name>
          <List>
             <Media>
                <path>C:\Users\Tchiko\Videos\Suit Tie (Official Lyric Video).mp4</path>
                <name>Suit Tie (Official Lyric Video).mp4</name>
                <type>Video</type>
             </Media>
         </List>
     </Playlist>
     <Playlist>
        <Name>Hip hop</Name>
          <List>
            <Media>
              <path>C:\Users\Tchiko\Videos\Suit Tie (Official Lyric Video).mp4</path>
              <name>Suit Tie (Official Lyric Video).mp4</name>
              <type>Video</type>
            </Media>
         </List>
      </Playlist>
</ArrayOfPlaylist>
```

Before loading my playlist, I want to check if a user corrupted the file by hand.
I need to check if the format XML is well, in order to avoid conflicts after deserialization.

**EDIT :**
Version to avoid error for not-well format :

```
        using (var fs = new FileStream("playlist.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Playlist>));
                if (fs.Length > 0)
                    pl = (ObservableCollection<Playlist>)xml.Deserialize(fs);
                else
                    pl = new ObservableCollection<Playlist>();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {  
                pl = new ObservableCollection<Playlist>();
            }
        }
```

Thanks for helps

Comment: if xml is corrupted, serialization will fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure XML validity you'll need to define an XML Schema. An XML Schema declares what tags, in what order and with what type of values are allowed in your XML.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8781/C-XML-Schema-Validator) is an article about how to validate XML against a Schema.

If your XML is not well-formed (as in, the user didn't close a tag or something of the sort), deserialization will fail and you'll get an `InvalidOperationException` with more details in the `InnerException`. See [XmlSerializer.Deserialize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc221bxx.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Yeah I put my code in a try, catch, I can avoid the error now. Thanks  
I put my code in edit part